# How to put variable on UICollectionView and get by function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables, cell

I need help for put variable on UICollectionView cell and get later by function in ViewController.swift
I try this code, but have problems get variable in cell.idyoutube.text

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (collectionView == self.collectionView1)
    {
        var cell : FeaturedCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifierFeatured, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeaturedCollectionViewCell

        var imageFilename: UIImage!


        let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite/images/imagestvos/feature-\(indexPath.row).jpg")!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)


                    imageFilename = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    cell.featuredImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    cell.idyoutube.text = "Rqr3w8scm2E"
     }


        task.resume()

        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()

}
```

and here, this is the function that is activate by click, but have problem fot get a `idyoutube.tex` variable.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell : FeaturedCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifierFeatured, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeaturedCollectionViewCell
    let mylink = cell.idyoutube.text
}
```

I do not know whether to reach idyoutube I go to: `let cell : FeaturedCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifierFeatured, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeaturedCollectionViewCell`

Comment: How many collection view you have? why this code is added:- ' if (collectionView == self.collectionView1)
    {'

Comment: have a four, but only use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `-dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` method in -`didSelectItemAtIndexPath` call, because this call is actually tries to get free cell from the cells' pool and not representing the cell you are tapping.

You need `-[UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:]` call with the index path, passed to `-didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method.
And in the returned cell, you will find your stored `idyoutube.text` property.

Comment: Hi! thanks :) ... I do not know if I understand.
You mean something?  `let cell : FeaturedCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath as! FeaturedCollectionViewCell`

Comment: Yes, but setting data variable to the View object is not good idea, because it's not ok with MVC pattern.
If you have an original array with Data objects, you can just lookup from it with indexPath.row property.